# Is there a way to throttle/slow a PHP script without missing streaming results from STDOUT?

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm testing out an interesting ["threading" concept](http://www.funkynerd.com/knowledgebase/articles/2) in PHP. Basically, I'm working to have a parent process spawn children that do stuff and return the results back to the parent via STDOUT in sort of a callback manner.

The way [my example](http://www.funkynerd.com/knowledgebase/articles/2)  does it, the inner loop is too tight and burns 99% CPU:

```
while(true){
        $ret = $thread->Listen();
        if( $ret == 'DOINGSTUFF' ){
                break;
        }
}
```

I'd like to tone this while loop down to looping every 5 seconds using, for example, a `sleep()`. This brings CPU utilization to a much more rational level; however I'm concerned it will then "miss" some of the children "threads" returning results in case one child finishes during the parent's sleeping process.

Can a PHP expert tell me whether this concern is well founded and if so, whether there's anything I can do to cope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example uses `proc_open`, which isn't exactly multi-threading. Anyway, when using `proc_open`, the pipes streams will be available as long as `proc_close` is not called, even if the process has actually terminated:

```
$proc = proc_open('which ls', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
sleep(5);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // output '/bin/ls'

$proc = proc_open('which ls', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
sleep(5);
proc_close($proc);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // E_WARNING: $pipes[1] not a valid stream
```

Also, it is not necessary to use `sleep`. Usually, you don't want a script hanging for 5 seconds every pass doing nothing. Use [usleep](http://php.net/usleep) instead, which will also reduce the CPU usage but will still make the script responsive:

```
while (true) {
   // do stuff
   usleep(50);
}
```

The above will sleep for 50 micro-seconds, leaving CPU cycles to other running processes.

As for pure multi-threading, it is not possible in PHP. All you can do is fork a process. The difference with actual forking and the method you use (`proc_open`) is that parent process data (variables, etc.) are forked to the child process as well. Forking should not be used in web applications, but only command-line programs, because web servers do not support it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you have already noticed, while(true) is the one burning the CPU and you can't "slow" the thing down. You want your app to behave as a listener, say a socket - it is active only when something wants to talk to it, otherwise it just stays dormant and "listens".
You should really create a listener on one of the ports and re-try your example, emulating a listener will only burn up CPU cycles for no reason. It makes inter-process communication easier too as you got a server and bunch of clients (processes) connected to it so you can share resources any way you like.

Also, re: threading in PHP - all you can do is fork a process, which isn't really threading and is a burden for the OS. Unless there's something that you really want to do in parallel, you should avoid forking at all costs.